# WordPress - remove action defined within plugin class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

So I have this plugin code

```
class WC_List_Grid {

 public function __construct() {
   add_action( 'wp' , array( $this, 'setup_gridlist' ) , 20);
 }

 function setup_gridlist() {
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $this, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 30);
 }

 function gridlist_toggle_button() {?>
                <nav class="gridlist-toggle">
                    <a href="#" id="grid" title="<?php _e('Grid view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle'); ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-grid-view"></span> <em><?php _e( 'Grid view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle' ); ?></em></a>
                    <a href="#" id="list" title="<?php _e('List view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle'); ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-exerpt-view"></span> <em><?php _e( 'List view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle' ); ?></em></a>
                </nav>
 <?php }
}
```

I want to change the content of the **gridlist_toggle_button** function. 
This is how I am planning to change the content of that function. Like writing another function with almost the same html as the original one but bits of my changes. Something like

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','new_gridlist_toggle_button')
function new_gridlist_toggle_button() {?>
                <nav class="gridlist-toggle">
                    <a href="#" class="grid-view" title="<?php _e('Grid view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle'); ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-grid-view"></span> <em><?php _e( 'Grid view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle' ); ?></em></a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-view" title="<?php _e('List view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle'); ?>"><span class="dashicons dashicons-exerpt-view"></span> <em><?php _e( 'List view', 'woocommerce-grid-list-toggle' ); ?></em></a>
                </nav>
 <?php }
}
```

That way, I won't have to change the plugin files directly

For that, I am trying to remove its related action.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $this, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 30);
```

So that I may use my own code. But I can't seem to remove this action. I have tried this so far.

**Method 1:**

```
global $WC_List_Grid    ;
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $WC_List_Grid, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 100);
```

**Method 2:**

```
function remove_plugin_actions(){
 global $WC_List_Grid   ;
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $WC_List_Grid, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 100); 
}
add_action('init','remove_plugin_actions');
```

**Method 3**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( 'WC_List_Grid', 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 100);
```

None of them seems to work.

With a bit of brainstorming, I think there could be two possible causes.

1. Its not working because the action I want to remove is not directly attached to the hook. Its action inside action.
2. I am trying to block the output of gridlist_toggle_button via functions.php. But if the plugins load before functions.php then the function to be blocked away is already being called and hence it is always showing output.

I am no good with OOP at all. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever `$wc_lg = new WC_List_Grid()` is instantiated, its going to trigger [`wp`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) hook. Right after global WP class object is set up, the instance `$wg_lg` is going to call `setup_gridlist()` on itself. Its going to trigger `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` hook. And whenever that happens, again `$wg_lg` is going to call a function on itself. Namely `gridlist_toggle_button()`.

> I want to change the content of the gridlist_toggle_button function

Why not just to change it inside plugin ? Like override everything whats inside it.

> global $WC_List_Grid;

How do you know that `$WC_List_Grid` has its name? Its just a class name. It can be instantiated under any name like `$foo` or `$bar`.

I assume that you are coding in functions.php file of your template. Plugins are being loaded before functions.php and `remove_action()` can only work after `add_action()` happend.

> Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority
>   arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both
>   filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

So this should actually work just for removing the action, but how that helps you to change content inside of the function? :

```
remove_action(
    'woocommerce_before_shop_loop',
    array('WC_List_Grid', 'gridlist_toggle_button'),
    30
);
```

*Notice that you were using priority 100*

**EDIT**

I found out that `do_action('woocommerce_archive_description')` happens in [archive-product.php](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/files/templates-archive-product/) and in [wc-template-functions.php](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/files/includes-wc-template-functions/) right before `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` hook actions are being executed in plugin. Try to use this:

```
function remove_plugin_actions(){
   global $WC_List_Grid;
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array( $WC_List_Grid, 'gridlist_toggle_button' ), 30); 
}
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description','remove_plugin_actions');
```

Comment: Please review my updated question. And I already tried this method and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you try with priority 30 or 100? Have you tried with no priority ?

Comment: Tried with all, 30 and 100 and no priority. I think your point "Plugins are being loaded before functions.php" is the reason. Because I am trying to block the output of gridlist_toggle_button. But as you have suggested, if the plugins load before functions.php then that function is already being called and hence it is showing output always.

Comment: Did you find out the variable name of WP_List_Grid instance ? Is it `$WP_List_Grid` since you tried to access it with global ?

Comment: Yup. It is $WC_List_Grid