# remove style/scripts defined within plugin class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Similar to this question [WordPress - remove action defined within plugin class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639146/wordpress-remove-action-defined-within-plugin-class)

i don't want to remove the whole action, if they update something, it will be overwrite.

I just want to remove one style enqueued in the class-wc-admin-assets.php.
But the file it's included inside a action with enclose.

So using this will not work:

```
function myFunctionToRemove(){
    wp_dequeue_style('jquery-ui-style');
    wp_deregister_style('jquery-ui-style');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','myFunctionToRemove');
```

Is there a way to dequeue only one script?

The style that i want to dequeue it's 'jquery-ui-style' on class-wc-admin-assets.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script is being enqueued on the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action you be able dequeue using your function, you likely just need to use a later priority.

```
function myFunctionToRemove(){
    wp_dequeue_style('jquery-ui-style');
    wp_deregister_style('jquery-ui-style');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts','myFunctionToRemove', 11 );
```

Try it with a priority of 11 and if that doesn't work try 999.

Comment: What version of WooCommerce are you using? I have tested this with a priority of 11 and it does work on version 2.6.1

Comment: I'm usgin 2.6.1 too, i'm gonna test again, but i already tested with 10, 20, 100, 1000 etc.

Comment: well, it worked, i work with cache disabled on my developer tool. i don't know why don't worked before, and now it worked